# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'options.cache')

Tags: react-native, apollo

I am creating a react native app with Apollo client with Expo
I get the error when trying to run the app in ios simulator

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
Event: {screen: EventScreen},
});

const client = new ApolloClient();
const RootComponent = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
   <RootComponent />
  </ApolloProvider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Kunkur', () => App);`
export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add cache and link to the options of apollo client.

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';


const client = new ApolloClient(
{
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: new HttpLink(
  {
   uri: 'http://your.graphql.url/graphql'
  })
}
```